# Finding vertical asymptote

Tags: algebra-precalculus

When finding the vertical asymptote of a rational function why can only the denominator$ = 0$ and not both the numerator and the denominator? both are undefined for $x$...

For example, for

$F(x) = \frac{3(x-9)(x+3)}{6(x-3)(x+3)}$

why can't $x = -3$?

Comment: the terms $(x+3)$ would cancel out? And after you cancel the terms, $F(-3)$ would have a denominator $\ne 0$ (in this example)

Comment: just draw the graph , where are the asymtopes? (asymtopes belong to geometry not to algebra, so draw)

Comment: what about $\frac{x}{x^2}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a vertical asymptote exists at $x = x_0$, then the function approaches $-\infty$ or $\infty$ as $x$ approaches $x_0$ from above ($x > x_0$) or from below ($x < x_0$).  That is not the case when the zero in the denominator is cancelled by a zero in the numerator.

If $x \neq \pm 3$, then

$$F(x) = \frac{3(x - 9)(x + 3)}{6(x - 3)(x + 3)} = \frac{x - 9}{2(x - 3)}$$

Thus, as $x$ approaches $-3$ (but is not equal to $-3$), the value of the function approaches

$$\frac{-3 - 9}{2(-3 - 3)} = \frac{-12}{2(-6)} = 1$$

We write

$$\lim_{x \to -3} F(x) = 1$$

Thus, the function approaches a finite value as $x$ approaches $-3$.  In terms of the graph, at $x = -3$, you have a point discontinuity (a hole in the graph) at the point $(-3, 1)$.

Observe that as $x$ approaches $3$ from above, $F(x)$ approaches $-\infty$ since the denominator is positive for $x > 3$ and approaching $0$ while the numerator, which is negative when $3 < x < 9$, approaches $-6$ (when $F(x)$ is expressed in simplest form).  We write

$$\lim_{x \to 3^+} F(x) = -\infty$$

As $x$ approaches $3$ from below, $F(x)$ approaches $\infty$ since the denominator is negative for $x < 3$ and approaching zero while the numerator, which is also negative for $x < 3$, approaches $-6$ (when $F(x)$ is expressed in simplest form).  We write

$$\lim_{x \to 3^-} F(x) = \infty$$

Since $F(x)$ approaches $-\infty$ as $x$ approaches $3$ from above and $F(x)$ approaches $\infty$ as $x$ approaches $3$ from below, $x = 3$ is a vertical asymptote of the graph of $F(x)$.